# Linux Kernel Compile-time options for Seagate IDE drive

Tags: compiling, linux-kernel, configuration

I am configuring linux kernel 3.12.14 obtained from linux.org for compiling using 'make gconfig'. My question is what options exactly I need to enable to make it work for my Seagate IDE HDD? I am compiling it for my other PC that has this HDD (not on which I am performing compilation).

Comment: IDE interface is quite common and should just work as is by default.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check under >Device Drivers that "Serial ATA and Parallel ATA drivers" is <*>
and as said in Help Section,  make sure that you know the name of your (S)ATA host adaptater because you will be asked for it (lspci is your friend).

Comment: That other system is currently running windows. And its a IDE drive, that is different from SATA.